# How do i get Window.innerWidth/height data into another function?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use scroll to the center of the page automatically when opening.

What I am trying to do is use the data from `window.innerwidth` divided by 2 in the function

```js
function Scrolldown() {
     window.scroll(0,300); 
}

window.onload = Scrolldown;
```

but to no avail. what am i doing wrong?

```
function Scrolldown() {
     window.scroll(((Window.innerwidth)/2),300); 
}

window.onload = Scrolldown;
```

Comment: Can you describe what is happening? Or is nothing happening at alle? Have you tried to `console.log()` your values? -- Also on a note, your `Window.innerWidth` is written with capital letter. Make sure it's not just a typo and try it with `window.innerWidth`

Comment: Jesus christ im an idiot. Yes i wrote with capital letters and obviously window.innerWidth/2 is too large of a number and not the center. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @hoargarth ! Yes i wrote with capital letters and obviously window.innerWidth/2 is too large of a number and not the center.

Danke!

i guess im living up to my screen name!